# Include path does not include folder

Tags: doxygen

I have a project

```
include
- docs
| - Doxyfile
- GooseFEM
| - ElementQuad4.h
| - ...
```

whereby my `Doxyfile` contains

```
INPUT = ../include
```

and the source files start with

```cpp
/**
Lorem ipsum

\file ElementQuad4.h
*/
```

All works fine, except that the displayed include path in the documentation is `#include <ElementQuad4.h>` (see screenshot) whereas I would like it to show what the user really has to do, and that is `#include <GooseFEM/ElementQuad4.h>`. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Do I understand it correct that in your code you have `#include <ElementQuad4.h>` and in the documentation you would like to see `#include <GooseFEM/ElementQuad4.h>`? Note that for the `\file` command it is not necessary to use the name of the file when the `\file` is in the file it documents.

Comment: In the code I indeed use relative paths (with `"..."` not `<...>`) such as `#include "ElementQuad4.h"`. But the user should use the installed library such that it should `#include <GooseFEM/ElementQuad4.h>`.

Comment: The thing is, the `include <ElementQuad4.h>` shown in the screenshot is not something written explicit by me. Unless I understand `\file` incorrectly, and I should write `\file GooseFEM/ElementQuad4.h` instead of `\file ElementQuad4.h`

Comment: I think that the information is a bit hidden in the documentation under `STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH` When set to e.g. `dummy` you will see the full path and when setting `STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH` to the part of the path till `GooseFEM` it looks like you probably get the requested results.

Comment: Thanks a lot @albert indeed, by specifying `STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH` I can get what I want by stripping one level less deep